# In the field of engineering, can GRE General test score be substituted with GRE Math score?

Tags: gre

In the field of engineering, can GRE General test score be substituted with GRE Math score?

Suppose a US university requires GRE general test score for PhD program, if an applicant sends GRE Math score, will that be enough?

Comment: Probably not, but the only way to find out is to ask the university, not to ask random folks like me.

Comment: The GRE General test includes tests of verbal reasoning and analytical writing. I don't think the scores on those sections can be predicted from GRE Math scores, so a Math score would not tell them everything they would want to find out from the general test.

Comment: By "GRE Math", are you referring to the GRE subject test in Math, or just the quantitative part of the general GRE?  The subject test is much more advanced and much more difficult, and wouldn't usually be taken by engineers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a general GRE test required if I have already passed a GRE Subject Test?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/is-a-general-gre-test-required-if-i-have-already-passed-a-gre-subject-test)

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much all programs will reject your application without consideration if you do not submit everything they request.  Some places are flexible; they may be willing to accept either test score.  (Some of the department at my university, including my department, are willing to take any one relevant score.)  However, such programs will almost always state this explicitly in their graduate application guidelines.  If you think a program might be willing to accept the substitution, you can always contact their director of graduate admissions or director of graduate studies and ask.  Chances are strongly against their saying yes, but it probably will not hurt your chances if you ask.

Comment: which uni r u in?

Comment: I work as a mid-level American research university--a large state school.